# CSS positioning and clearfix

Tags: html, css

When I wrote website template I had frustrating problem with positioning. When i use relative positioning to move higher last element of the page, on the bottom I had empty space. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
        <title>Clearfix test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>a</header>
        <div id="pageWrapper">
            <div id="page"></div>
        </div>
        <!--<footer></footer>-->
    </body>
 </html>

* {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: white;
 }
body {
     background: grey;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
 }

header {
     width: 900px;
     height: 150px;
     border: 1px solid red;
}

 #pageWrapper {
     position:relative;
     width: 850px;
     height: 600px;
     top: -40px;
     border: 1px solid green;
 }

 #page {
     position:absolute;
     top: 25px;
     left: 25px;
     border: 1px solid darkgoldenrod;
     height: 550px;;
     width: 800px;
 }
```

There is any way to remove this empty area at page bottom ? I was trying to use clearfix but without any luck.

Comment: that is coz of the height specified

Comment: You could use `margin-top` instead of relative positioning with `top` on `#pageWrapper`.

Comment: This is good idea to replace relative positioning by margin-top, then remove div with absolute positioning and this will be working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
*{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;   
     }
    body {
         background: grey;     
     }
    #container{
        width: 900px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }
    header {
         width: 900px;
         height: 150px;
         border: 1px solid red;
    }

     #pageWrapper {
         width:800px;
         padding:40px;
         margin:0px auto;    
         border: 1px solid green;
         margin-top:-40px;
     }

     #page {
         border: 1px solid darkgoldenrod; 
         height:500px;
     }
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
        <title>Clearfix test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="container">
        <header>a</header>
        <div id="pageWrapper">
            <div id="page"></div>
        </div> 
        </div>      
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have given `top:-40px`

it is `#pagewrapper` space

remove it and enjoy

Comment: I can't do this, becouse #pageWrapper must be in this position, it must grapple with the header.

Comment: then give height:110px to header

Answer (score 0):

In your css, `#pagewrapper` instead of `top:-40px`; just give `top:0px;`

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pDtwE/37/)